# Filtering from a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
findit::[Productdb]->Bool
findit para = do
          let para1 = head para
          let para2 = head [b|(a,b,c,d)<-para1]
          if(para2=="him") then return False
          else return True
test = do 
    u <- readFile "cart1.txt"
    let v = read u ::[[Productdb]]
    let putit=filter findit v
    putStrLn(show(putit)
```

When it is executed, I get errors that `findit` returns `IO Bool` instead of `Bool`, and the `filter` statement comes with an error that it only accepts functions which return `Bool`.

Comment: Could you show the definition of type `Productdb`? I think that will allow for better answers

Comment: type Code=Int
type Name= String
type Price = Int
type Quantity= Int

type Productdb=(Code,Name,Price,Quantity)

Answer (score 6):

Do-notation is only for use with monads such as `IO`. `findit` returns a plain `Bool`, so you should not use do-notation to define it. You could write it like this:

```
findit para = let para1 = head para
                  para2 = head [b|(a,b,c,d)<-para1]
              in  if (para2=="him") then False else True
```

Note that his is using a `let ... in ...` expression instead of the form of `let` allowed in do-notation.

However, this is not very idiomatic Haskell. The `if` expression can be replaced with `para2 /= "him"`, and the applications of `head` and the list comprehension can be replaced with pattern matching:

```
findit (((_, b, _, _):_):_) = b /= "him"
```

Now, it's also easy to make your function *total*, so that it's also defined for empty lists by adding a catch-all case below it:

```
findit _ = -- something that makes sense for your use case
```

This is generally a good idea, because total functions are nicer to work with because they don't fail because of an unexpected input.

Finally, I would suggest choosing better names for variables and functions in your code. Looking at your code, I can tell what it does at a "mechanical" level, but I have no idea what it's *for*, or even if it's doing what it's supposed to be doing. Naming things well is an important way to help communicating your intent to other programmers.

Comment: Thanx hammar..now if i want to take input from user and to compare the input insteaad of "him" .how should i do that??

Comment: @Himanshi: You can make it another argument of `findit` and for example use `getLine` to read it in `main`, similar to how you did with `v`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `return` in `return True` and `return False`. `return` has the type

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

It seems that `m` is defaulting to `IO` here, but in any case, findit is an ordinary function -- no need for return.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what you are trying to do, but I will give you some code which resembles what I think you want.

```
type Code=Int
type Name= String
type Price = Int
type Quantity= Int
type Product = (Code, Name, Price, Quantity)

-- test data
product1 = (1, "one", 123, 111)
product2 = (2, "two", 321, 11)
product3 = (3, "three", 44, 1)
product4 = (4, "him", 55, 22)
product_db = [[product1, product2], [product4, product2], [product3]]

-- @Hamanshi: please explain how this could make sense (especially the call to head seems suspicious)
findit :: [Product] -> Bool
findit para = let para2 = head [b | (a,b,c,d) <- para] in para2 /= "him"

test :: IO ()
test = putStrLn $ show $ filter findit product_db
```

I changed the `Productdb` to `Product` because I think that the tuple represents a single product, not a DB of products.

Further, you could use a real data type: `data Product = Product { code :: Code, name :: Name, price :: Price, quantity :: Quantity }`, this will give you selectors for products `name product1 == "one"`
Then you can rewrite findit this way: `findit para = "him" /= (name (head para))`